# how do i get app secret for my page?

Tags: facebook

I need to grab the latest post from a facebook like page. I'm an administrator on the page so I have the app id but reading the docs looks like I need the app secret so I can then get an access token. So I followed instructions and went to the developer app. Problem is the page doesn't show up as an app so I can't access the ifo I need

When I visit https://graph.facebook.com/MY_PAGE_ID/feed?limit=1 i just get an oauth exception saying I need an access token.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone gets similarly confused.....Turns out I needed to create an app in order to get an access token and secret which I could then use in my url...which looks like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/my_app_id_here/feed?access_token=My_access_token_here

The feed? bit gets me the pages news feed and the access token was generated once I had created an app using my facebook account. The app id can be obtained by going to the like page and clicking on the edit tab next to about (You must be an admin of that page to see this).